# Setting Git username and email without using .gitconfig?

Tags: git, dotfiles

I have a dotfiles repository for macOS which contains the `.gitconfig` file. I would like to keep `username` and `email` separate from this file so that these variables are never committed as part of my public dotfiles repository.

One approach I have seen is to specify a file called `.extra`, keeping it in the `~/` directory (it is referenced it in `.bash_profile`) and set the Git variables in that file, so that they are external to my public repository, i.e. any public changes I make to `.gitconfig` will **not** include the `username` and `email`.

The problem is none of the approaches to setting these values are working for me. Following every attempt I get the following message:

> Your name and email address were configured automatically based
>   on your username and hostname. Please check that they are accurate.
>   You can suppress this message by setting them explicitly:
>
> `git config --global user.name "Your Name"`
>
> `git config --global user.email you@example.com`
>
> After doing this, you may fix the identity used for this commit with:
>
> `git commit --amend --reset-author`

I have the following in my `.extra` file, and his failed to work:

> `GIT_AUTHOR_NAME="First Last"`
>
> `GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="First Last"`
>
> `EMAIL=email@example.com`

I have tried various approaches using these variables and others, as well as including and excluding quotation marks, and even prefixing these lines with `export`. At a bit of a loss!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I figured out the solution:

Add the following to your dotfiles' `.gitconfig` file:

> `[user]
>       # These values are set in ~/.gitconfig_local`
>
> `[include]
>       path = ~/.gitconfig_local`

Create a file in `~/` called `.gitconfig_local` and add the values you don't want committed or made public in your `.gitconfig` file. In this case:

> `[user]
>       name = First Last
>       email = email@example.com`

As you might guess, the `[include]` command "links" to the local, secondary configuration file which is outside the repository and thus private. The remainder of your settings in `.gitconfig` such as your aliases, colour and editor settings etc. will still be public.

Comment: Didn't know you could include config files from git config files. Nice solution

Answer (score 3):

All settings can be set on a per repository basis : just drop the `--global` from your `git config` commands :

```
# from inside your repo :
git config user.name "Your Name"
git config user.email you@example.com
```

These config settings will then be stored in the `.git/config` file (in the repo folder), and will take precedence over global config options.

This works for any git config option (aliases, colors, ...)

*note* : you will have to repeat the config for any new clone you make, or for any other repo where you want to use this identity

Comment: …or one can add `--local` to be 100% explicit.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config` (usually `~/.config/git/config`) for most of your configuration and include it in your dotfiles repository. You can then add `.gitconfig` to `.gitignore` and use it for `user.name`, `user.email` and other values you don't want committed.

See the [git-config documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#FILES) for the order of which files it reads.